# If I want to talk about a person, but not one in specific, should I use: "Subject", "One" or "Persons"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, subjects

I'd like to use a noun to mention a person, but not a specific one, like generalising.

Should I say it like this?

> It allows the subject to speak for themselves.

Or like this?

> It allows persons to speak for themselves.

Or this?

> It allow one to speak for themselves.

Or is there any other option I have no idea about it?

Comment: Just go for people.

Comment: Even if it's formally speaking? Like, in a research?

Comment: This is a singular-they question in disguise.

Comment: So can I say it like this? "examining two cases whithin the social networks' context in which people start the dialogue (...)". In this example, people has this idea of a ramdom/any person

Comment: FYI *one* -> *oneself* not *themselves*

Comment: Thank you...And could you, please, help me with the question above your comment?

Comment: I'll prefer using the word "persons".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Subject", although not necessarily wrong, doesn't really work here unless you're talking about someone in a medical trial or someone who is "subject" to someone else.

I think "one" sounds best, although "persons" could be okay.

As a pointer, the third person plural reflexive pronoun "themselves" is incompatible with the indefinite pronoun "one". You have to use "oneself" as a complement if you're going to use "one".

Comment: To formal writing, is it OK to use "one", or "persons" is more formal?

Comment: I would say that the use of "persons" makes for a more archaic construction. In the UK, it was rather observable that texts would use "persons", but it's not so common nowadays. Both "one" and "persons" are rather formal but I think "one" is probably more suited in a modern setting.

Comment: and what should I use to talk about the possessive cases of "one"...Like: "one cannot bring his/her/their/its(?) own food"

Comment: Use the singular their.

Comment: @LoureiroGui use *one's*

Comment: "One's" sounds incredibly awkward and unnatural. "One cannot bring one's own food" is something you would never hear. Ever. I wouldn't even use pronouns to clarify the recipient here; I think they can be assumed if you simply use the construction: "food purchased externally is strictly prohibited on these premises."

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "It allows **individuals** to speak for themselves."

Answer (score 0):

*Subject* would be better if we wanted to posit a hypothetical subject that we can continue to discuss throughout a longer passage. This allows for continuity (we can talk about what options might be available to a subject after a previously considered matter) or restriction (we may have already qualified what sort of person would be a subject).

On it's own, without this use, it's meaningless ("what subject?").

*One* is used to make a statement that applies to everyone or practically everyone. In this case the *themelves* should be changed to *oneself*.

*People* would be preferred over *persons*.

*You* is often used informally, in a manner almost the opposite to how *one* is used - you take something that is general but you describe the effect upon the addressee in particular to make that point.

Answer (score 0):

The use of "one" in  contemporary English is very confusing.   I most romance languages that are more inflected than English, the noun "one" is widely used when not speaking about a particular individual but in general. For example in Spanish "*uno* debe siempre ser cortés" or in French "Qu'est-ce *on* va faire?"

However, the use of "one" in spoken English often sounds awkward "One must be true to oneself" "When one is on a date, one must make sure to keep one's phone off"

As it can be seen, by the examples above that "one" is a tricky noun to use.

R.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to EL&U. We appreciate your answer. You can make this a better answer by providing links, even in answers responding to seemingly opinion-based questions.